# Center alignment of text with matrices

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am trying to reproduce output similar to the following:

[image]

Notice the center alignment of the Y, X, beta, and e with the matrices above them.

My attempt for something similar (assume all values/symbols are correct as given):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
y_4 \\
y_5 \\
y_6
\end{bmatrix} &&= &&\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
1 & x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
1 & x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} \\
1 & x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} \\
1 & x_{51} & x_{52} & x_{53} \\
1 & x_{61} & x_{62} & x_{63}
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\beta_3 
\end{bmatrix} &&+ &&\begin{bmatrix}
e_1 \\
e_2 \\
e_3 \\
e_4 \\
e_5 \\
e_6
\end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbf{Y} &&= &&\mathbf{X} &&\boldsymbol{\beta} &&+ &&\boldsymbol{\epsilon}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do that would be to use an `array`:

[image]

### Note:

- Around the `=` and `+` note the useage of `{}` to obtain the proper relational/binary operator spacing.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
y_4 \\
y_5 \\
y_6
\end{bmatrix} &{}={} &\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
1 & x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
1 & x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} \\
1 & x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} \\
1 & x_{51} & x_{52} & x_{53} \\
1 & x_{61} & x_{62} & x_{63}
\end{bmatrix}
&\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\beta_3 
\end{bmatrix} &{}+{} &\begin{bmatrix}
e_1 \\
e_2 \\
e_3 \\
e_4 \\
e_5 \\
e_6 \\[2.5ex]
\end{bmatrix} \\
\mathbf{Y} &{}={} &\mathbf{X} &\boldsymbol{\beta} &{}+{} &\boldsymbol{\epsilon}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```